# A quick question on closed intervals of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let  $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric topology and $a<b$. If there are closed sets $A$ and $B$ such that $a\in A$ , $b\in B$ and  $[a,b]=A\cup B$,  show that $A \cap B\neq\emptyset$, without using the fact that intervals are connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

If we can use connectedness then this is obvious, though this still seems that it should be quite clear to show but I am struggling to show it without using connectedness, so any help is really needed and appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What can you say about the supremum of $A$..?

Comment: $\sup A$ exists as $A$ is bounded by b and is in $A$ as $A$ is closed. I tried then taking an open open with centre $\sup A$ using various radii ($b-a, 2(b-a)$ etc to find a common point for $A$ and $B$ but am still stuck.  Also tried showing that $\sup A= \inf B$ and $\inf B\in B$ as it is closed but am a bit stuck, can you elaborate more or put me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Comment: @EmilioNovati The question asks to show that $A \cap B$ is NOT empty.

Comment: Oooh, thanks. My blunder!! :(

Comment: There is no hope in trying to prove that $\sup A = \inf B$: take $A=[0,2]$ and $B=[1,3]$.

Comment: @lhf sup $A$ is not necessarily inf $B$ but is clearly contained in $A\cap B$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Use bisection. Let $m$ be the midpoint of $[a.b]$. If $m \in A$, consider $[m,b]$; otherwise, $m \in B$, and consider $[a,m]$. Repeat. You'll get a sequence of closed nested intervals $[a_n,b_n]$, with $a_n\in A$ and $b_n \in B$.

Answer (score 1):

$s = \sup(A)$ exists, as $A$ is bounded.

Because $A$ is closed, $s \in A$. (For every $\epsilon>0$, $s - \epsilon$ is not an upperbound of $A$ (as $s$ is the least upper bound), so some $a$ exists between $s-\epsilon < a \le s$. So every $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $s$ intersects $A$, so $s \in \overline{A} = A$.) We can assume $s < b$, or we are done ($b \in A \cap B$).

We also know that $(s,b] \subseteq B$ (there cannot be members of $A$ above $s$). $[s,b] = \overline{(s,b]} \subseteq B$, so $s \in B$, and we know that $s \in A \cap B$. Done.